# In Java, how to dynamically put any annotations the declaration of classes within the specified package ?

Tags: java, dynamic, annotations, package, put

In Java, how to dynamically put any annotations on the declaration of classes within the specified package ?

Is the package-info.java able to do it ?

How to write it if can ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless dynamical byte code generator such as [Javassist](http://www.jboss.org/javassist) is used.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you are asking for is some to automatically have all classes within a given package be annotated in some way.

That is not possible.

You could definitely do it with byte-code manipulation (either as part of the build process, or during class-loading), but that's a lot of work, and probably isn't the path you want to head down.

You probably need to rethink your approach here.

What is the annotation that you're trying to use, and why do you need all classes to have that annotation?

Comment: Please look this question, and help me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621962/in-actionscript-3-how-to-decode-from-xml-to-actionscript-class