# In ActionScript 3, how to decode from xml to ActionScript class?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, encoding, jaxb, decoding

In ActionScript 3, how to decode from xml to ActionScript class ?

I could encode from ActionScript class to xml by using XmlEncoder.

The xml schema I used at that time is this.

[schema1.xsd]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="user">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="userDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This schema is created by Ant(schemagen) task using POJO(User.java) with no annotations.

But I could not decode from xml to ActionScript class by using this schema and XmlDecoder.
(In correct, I can't be done casting from Object type to User type.)

I want not to put any annotations like @XmlRootElement or @XmlType in Java class.

However, I need a schema file for client side of ActionScript to marshal and unmarshall.

Please tell me any solutions or examples...

Answer (score 0):

The following class:

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class User {

    private String id;
    private String password;
    private Date userDate;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getUserDate() {
        return userDate;
    }

    public void setUserDate(Date userDate) {
        this.userDate = userDate;
    }

}
```

Can be used to unmarshal the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <id>123</id>
   <password>foo</password>
   <userDate>2011-01-07T09:15:00</userDate>
</root>
```

Using the following code without requiring any annotations on the User class:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);

        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<User> root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, User.class);

        User user = root.getValue();
        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        System.out.println(user.getUserDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Blaise! In Java, I think I will be able to write like this. But how to write in ActionScript 3 for using that xml ?